# Error: descriptor 'blit' requires a 'pygame.Surface' object but received a 'NoneType'

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a game. I wrote this code to create a sprite and its hitbox:

```
hg = pygame.image.load('hgrd1copy.jpg').set_colorkey(red)
hgbox = pygame.Rect(0 ,13 ,36 ,72)
pygame.Surface.blit(hg, hgbox)
```

I had originally put

```
windowSurface.blit(hg, hgbox)
```

but then I got an error telling me that my argument needed to be `pygame.Surface` not none.

However, when I changed the code to `pygame.Surface.blit`, it gives me this error code:
`TypeError: descriptor 'blit' requires a 'pygame.Surface' object but received a 'NoneType'`
What do I do?

Comment: ... Fix the code so that `hg` is not `None`.

Comment: `hg` is `None` since `set_colorkey(red)` is not returning a `pygame.Surface` object. You can verify that from [pygame's documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_colorkey) (`-> None` indicates the return type is `None`). To fix this, just do the "image loading" on one line (so that `hg` gets the returned surface) and the "color key setting" on its own line (e.g. `hg.set_colorkey(red)`)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the commemts  - y9u have to load your image in one line of code, and in another line call the  `set_colorkey` method on the image read. And them, `blit` should be called as a method from an existing surface - not from the `Surface` class. (With the code as it is now in the question, how would the program "know" *where* to blit the image to?

So, assuming your screen is on the  `windowSurface` variable you describe, this should work:

```
hg = pygame.image.load('hgrd1copy.jpg')
hg.set_colorkey(red)
hgbox = pygame.Rect(0, 13, 36, 72)
windowSurface.blit(hg, hgbox)
```

Comment: I moved `set_colorkey` to a different line, which fixed my earlier problem, but now when I run my program red doesn't actually get taken out. I have checked that the red on the picture file and my program's definition are both (255,0,0). Do you have an idea why it is like this?