# pygame.Surface turning into NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a python file called `engine.py`. I have one specific function that I will put part of, due to knowing the function works fine:

```py
def set_image(self,path : str,spritesheet=None) -> pygame.Surface:
        if (path is not None) and (spritesheet is None): # if path is provided but spritesheet is not
            try:
                self.image = pygame.image.load(path)
                print(type(self.image))
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            except FileNotFoundError as e:
                raise e
```

But when I try to `blit()` the image result of the function, I get a `TypeError` stating that `pygame.Surface` must be the first argument, not `None`. I did some testing and found out that the function from `engine.py` works just fine, and that it does properly set `self.image`. But the program does not have its `self.image` to the `pygame.Surface` object.

Here's where the player object is declared and `player.image` is set:

```py
player = Engine.Player()

player.image = player.set_image('screensaver/blue_car.png',)
```

And here's where I try to `blit()` it onto my display surface (The line where the error pops up):

```py
display.blit(player.image, (0,0))
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45656895/error-descriptor-blit-requires-a-pygame-surface-object-but-received-a-none

Comment: This method doesn't return anything, so assigning its result to `player.image` is of course going to produce `None`.

Comment: In your function `set_image`, the try-except is unnecessary as all you do is catching the error and immediately raising it again, so you can remove it completely. It'll not change anything.

Comment: im doing other things than raising the error, I just removed it so as not to make the code unnecessarily confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set_image` is a method. The method does not return an image, but it sets the `image` and `rect` attributes of the object. Therefore:

<s>`player.image = player.set_image('screensaver/blue_car.png',)`</s>

```py
player.set_image('screensaver/blue_car.png')
```